# Type safe merge of object literals in typescript

Tags: typescript, merge, spread-syntax

I want to merge two typescript objects (using object spread):

```
var one = { a: 1 }
var two = { a: 2, b: 3 }
var m = {...one, ...two} // problem as property `a` is overwritten
```

I want to use the type system to ensure none of the properties in the second object overwrite any properties in the first.  I am not sure why the following solution does not work:

```
type UniqueObject<T extends {[K in keyof U]?: any}, U> =
    {[K in keyof U]: T[K] extends U[K] ? never : U[K]}

var one = { a: 1 }
var two1 = { a: 2, b: 3 }
var two1_: UniqueObject<typeof one, typeof two1> = two1 // errors correctly
var two2 = { a: undefined, b: 1 }
var two2_: UniqueObject<typeof one, typeof two2> = two2 // passes incorrectly
```

[Another version from a year ago](https://gist.github.com/AJamesPhillips/4b36d407d2824d8ba114a96122fd312f) which I thought worked at the time had `undefined extends U[K]` in the place of `T[K] extends U[K]`:

```
type UniqueObject<T extends {[K in keyof U]?: any}, U> =
    {[K in keyof U]: undefined extends T[K] ? U[K]: never}
```

Neither of these two work.  I suspect it is because the `undefined extends U[K]` or `T[K] extends U[K]` are both false as the property `K` in `T` is optional.  Not sure how or if it's possible to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both your versions are more or less equivalent - only the true/false branches in the conditional type are switched up.

The constraint `T extends {[K in keyof U]?: any}` is a bit problematic: when you remove `a` in `two`, the error `Type '{ a: number; }' has no properties in common with type '{ b?: any; }` is triggered, which actually should be the success case.

Be also aware, that the resulting type `merge` doesn't contain the merged type definition from both types. We can change the declaration up:

```
type UniqueObject<T, U> =
    T & { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? never : U[K] }
```

Now, the compiler correctly errors with a duplicate `a` property:

```
var one = { a: 1 }
var two = { a: 2, b: 3 }
//                                                        v a becomes never here
type Merge = UniqueObject<typeof one, typeof two> // { a: never; b: number; }
const res: Merge = { ...one, ...two } // errors now, cannot assign number to never
```

In the following I have simplified the type a bit and packed everything in a compact  helper function to control types + spread operator:

```
function mergeUnique<T extends object, U extends object & { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? never : U[K] }>(o1: T, o2: U) {
    return { ...o1, ...o2 }
}

const res21 = mergeUnique({ a: 1 }, { b: 3 })
const res22 = mergeUnique({ a: 1 }, { a: 2, b: 3 }) // error
const res23 = mergeUnique({ a: 1, c: 5 }, { b: 3 })
const res24 = mergeUnique({ a: 1}, { a: undefined }) // error
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=61&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwI4FcIHkBGArCBjYAHgBUAaWAPigF4BYAKCiamKgDIoBvKAbQGkoCOFADWEEAHsAZrAC6ALigCIAD2AQ4AEwDOo8dJZQA-FDgQAbhABOURTH6yoAXwYNzAQxsSzNLlHeKAIzObp5QwADuEr7cAVAATOSYigDMIfSgkFAAstYA5tDUsIioGDj4RJkQBt4Q5FUGkRJUAPQtfnFmllYA3FDJpigAtpjWfS70eN7awFBWENqKuVYFMVAAdJu15JvrTc5QbVDWVhJWunASEa70UihwBAjeUEP5EPDIaCTHaho6UBJygRyDAfuotLpAbgCOw-PxBMIxJIZDAFEowX9dEiDKwTF1rLZYA5nBQABQSQKKMgA+J2ACUXAYzDmEGAKCswm4uwpOy28XSEwYUzgMxZ2niwSKrxW7xKaFJsSCznI3AGaScdKF01m83F-Klbw+pQV-iVThVpoSSVSzgZRxOZy1Ip1C3iaQNMqN8sVUEC5DwigArMq-GrbU7Rbr4gAWXzSgpeiAmuLBc0dRT3TQQKRCCCaW2HdoOqwMIA)

Comment: Brilliant.  Thank you.  Yes the change to `K extends keyof T` is the key.  I added 3 more test cases and have made a suggested change.  Feel free to edit again as you wish.

Comment: Actually I've added a few more scenarios that it "incorrectly" types. I can't figure out a way to fix these at the moment  as it comes down to `keyof ({[index: string]: number})` => `string` which matches all `K in keyof U` and makes them `never`.

Comment: Hm, you have come up with some new cases here (lost a bit the track of the edited answer). The original question was about merging two object literals. Also objects with an explicit index signature type bring in another dimension. I suggest, you extend your question, if the answer didn't quite satisfy your needs or write your own answer instead. Cheers!

Comment: Agreed and apologies, brain v tired.  I've edited the question title to make it only about object literals, I've put back a minor edit (again please edit if you disagree), and I've asked a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/59689060/539490

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
type Merge<A, B> = { [K in keyof (A | B)]: K extends keyof B ? B[K] : A[K] };
```

This type allows you to specify any two objects, `A` and `B`.

From these, a mapped type whose keys are derived from available keys from either object is created.  The keys come from `keyof (A | B)`.

Each key is then mapped to the type of that key by looking up the appropriate type from the source.  If the key comes from `B`, then the type is the type of that key from `B`.  This is done with `K extends keyof B ?`.  This part asks the question, "is `K` a key from `B`" ?  To get the type of that key, `K`, use a property lookup `B[K]`.

If the key is not from `B`, it must be from `A`, thus the ternary is completed:

`K extends keyof B ? B[K] : A[K]`

All of this is wrapped in an object notation `{ }`, making this a mapped object type, whose keys are derived from two object and whose types map to the source types.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Taking [@ford04's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685402/539490) and expanding it for multiple optional values:

```
function safe_merge<
    O1,
    O2 extends { [K2 in keyof O2]: K2 extends keyof O1 ? never : O2[K2] },
    O3 extends { [K3 in keyof O3]: K3 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K3 extends keyof O2 ? never : O3[K3]) },
    O4 extends { [K4 in keyof O4]: K4 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K4 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K4 extends keyof O3 ? never : O4[K4])) },
    O5 extends { [K5 in keyof O5]: K5 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K5 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K5 extends keyof O3 ? never : ( K5 extends keyof O4 ? never : O5[K5]))) },
    O6 extends { [K6 in keyof O6]: K6 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K6 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K6 extends keyof O3 ? never : ( K6 extends keyof O4 ? never : (K6 extends keyof O5 ? never : O6[K6])))) },
    O7 extends { [K7 in keyof O7]: K7 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K7 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K7 extends keyof O3 ? never : ( K7 extends keyof O4 ? never : (K7 extends keyof O5 ? never : (K7 extends keyof O6 ? never : O7[K7]))))) },
    O8 extends { [K8 in keyof O8]: K8 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K8 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K8 extends keyof O3 ? never : ( K8 extends keyof O4 ? never : (K8 extends keyof O5 ? never : (K8 extends keyof O6 ? never : (K8 extends keyof O7 ? never : O8[K8])))))) },
    O9 extends { [K9 in keyof O9]: K9 extends keyof O1 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O2 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O3 ? never : ( K9 extends keyof O4 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O5 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O6 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O7 ? never : (K9 extends keyof O8 ? never : O9[K9]))))))) },
>(
    o1: O1,
    o2: O2 = ({} as any),
    o3: O3 = ({} as any),
    o4: O4 = ({} as any),
    o5: O5 = ({} as any),
    o6: O6 = ({} as any),
    o7: O7 = ({} as any),
    o8: O8 = ({} as any),
    o9: O9 = ({} as any),
): O1 & O2 & O3 & O4 & O5 & O6 & O7 & O8 & O9 {
    return { ...o1, ...o2, ...o3, ...o4, ...o5, ...o6, ...o7, ...o8, ...o9 }
}


const obj_1 = {1:1}
const obj_2 = {2:1}
const obj_3 = {3:1}
const obj_4 = {4:1}
const obj_5 = {5:1}
const obj_6 = {6:1}
const obj_7 = {7:1}
const obj_8 = {8:1}
const obj_9 = {9:1}


// should not error
safe_merge(obj_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9)


// declare objects with keys conflicting with existing objects
const obj_2_1 = {2:1, 1: 1}
const obj_2_1b = {2:1, 1: undefined}

const obj_3_1 = {3:1, 1:1}
const obj_3_2 = {3:1, 2:1}

const obj_4_1 = {4:1, 1:1}
const obj_4_2 = {4:1, 2:1}
const obj_4_3 = {4:1, 3:1}

const obj_5_1 = {5:1, 1:1}
const obj_5_2 = {5:1, 2:1}
const obj_5_3 = {5:1, 3:1}
const obj_5_4 = {5:1, 4:1}

const obj_6_1 = {6:1, 1:1}
const obj_6_2 = {6:1, 2:1}
const obj_6_3 = {6:1, 3:1}
const obj_6_4 = {6:1, 4:1}
const obj_6_5 = {6:1, 5:1}

const obj_7_1 = {7:1, 1:1}
const obj_7_2 = {7:1, 2:1}
const obj_7_3 = {7:1, 3:1}
const obj_7_4 = {7:1, 4:1}
const obj_7_5 = {7:1, 5:1}
const obj_7_6 = {7:1, 6:1}

const obj_8_1 = {8:1, 1:1}
const obj_8_2 = {8:1, 2:1}
const obj_8_3 = {8:1, 3:1}
const obj_8_4 = {8:1, 4:1}
const obj_8_5 = {8:1, 5:1}
const obj_8_6 = {8:1, 6:1}
const obj_8_7 = {8:1, 7:1}

const obj_9_1 = {9:1, 1:1}
const obj_9_2 = {9:1, 2:1}
const obj_9_3 = {9:1, 3:1}
const obj_9_4 = {9:1, 4:1}
const obj_9_5 = {9:1, 5:1}
const obj_9_6 = {9:1, 6:1}
const obj_9_7 = {9:1, 7:1}
const obj_9_8 = {9:1, 8:1}


// should error
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2_1b)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3_2)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4_3)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5_4)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6_4)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6_5)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_4)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_5)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7_6)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_4)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_5)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_6)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8_7)

safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_1)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_2)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_3)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_4)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_5)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_6)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_7)
safe_merge(obj_1, obj_2, obj_3, obj_4, obj_5, obj_6, obj_7, obj_8, obj_9_8)
```