# Type safe merge of index signature object types in typescript

Tags: typescript, merge, spread-syntax

[This question and answer covers object literals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59685402/539490) but the answer does not work when using index signature object types.  e.g:

```
type UniqueObject<T, U> = { [K in keyof U]: K extends keyof T ? never : U[K] }

export function mergeUnique <T, U, V> (
  a: T,
  b?: UniqueObject<T, U>,
  c?: UniqueObject<T & U, V>,
) {
  return {
    ...a,
    ...b,
    ...c,
  }
}

type Obj = { [index: string]: number | undefined }
const a: Obj = { a: undefined }
const b: Obj = { b: 3 }

// should all pass
const res01 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, { b: 3 })
const res02 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, b)
const res03 = mergeUnique(a, { b: 3 })                 // errors incorrectly ❌ `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'`
const res04 = mergeUnique(a, b)                        // errors incorrectly ❌ `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'`
const res05 = mergeUnique({ b: 3 }, { a: undefined })
const res06 = mergeUnique(b, { a: undefined })         // errors incorrectly ❌ `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'never'`
const res07 = mergeUnique({ b: 3 }, a)
const res08 = mergeUnique(b, a)                        // errors incorrectly ❌ `Argument of type 'Obj' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UniqueObject<Obj, { [x: string]: ...; }>'`

// should all fail
const res09 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, { a: undefined })
const res10 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, a)         // passes incorrectly ❌
const res11 = mergeUnique(a, { a: undefined })
const res12 = mergeUnique(a, a)                        // errors correctly  but reason wrong: `Argument of type 'Obj' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UniqueObject<Obj, { [x: string]: ...; }>'`
```

[Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=34&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwI4FcIHkBGArCBjYAHgBUAaWAPigF4oBvKAbQGkoE4oBrCEAewDNYAXQBcUVhAAewCHAAmAZy48BUYlAD8UOBABuEAE5QxMFkKgBfALAAoW1LC8DwKPxRwCCXhwC2hgOYQ8MhoUCTkMOQAalQAFLZQUACGYmQJUJgaJoioGDj4RGSUpOl4WbA5aFi4BCRQAGSw0RQlNgCU9OkGEMAoBhx06YkAdKNJrYkjo5gTk6PDeLPWNsu2oJBQ1TT0TOxyUmIKwAbs-qLaKD6YhlAAPlDu+-zsEHKWtnjeR8liW7QMKQe8ggzx0b2Wnzg30wvxw2wYMKgAGZ3nYbAB6dFQBQAC14KAANm8kgSCVAwEkFAoPl8XN0FAAGACM2z8BkCwVysQBYkeIJe4PICLEKIsbRpULpEEZACZWQEgpUINyfkCngLLORMOKbJDvvSGSjaGyOUrYuMdojRR1Jra7bbMVBDAYnEp2J8DN0CASQFBADLkUAABsRwNAAORwS7XAxhthKOC8FyUhQIfxwJKYAnQYC8KDrcM6fQxwMS-XShkAFnl7MVIWVFu19qbzcmjudrrYHicXuAPv9QZDGzDfNBr1jCHjieSVNT6cz2dz+agEb0hjDJd1tKgBoArNXTXWVVbNTtASONWLS1LGQA2fe1rkzU+84Gj8E2pttz0d93dgp9gNg1DZdzzBcdJyTGc0wzLM80XYCVyLdcr23csAHZ705NAjxFE8kh1PVrwZAAOTCzSffCWyou0vxdAw3S7T1-19QCAEF2UuWQXFUJcw2qcDtCnZNZxghdySSAwkj8GQjB4hCsLyGoiGqIUmEkQ5jlOc55gAbksChkLRR1cXxIlklJVwkgQAkUINABOMjDx5NV+TBE9nNA15LAIrd6SZBlHK5DzXwvchKObR0KSpaVOw9HsANs6UmRZY0FQU81VLPEK3MvTdJVQhQmTlVKa3Si1wuo6jaI7OLmKgQBeDcADl2MhQKVKW8KAAHcXTgfwxEDdj-E4uBuMEXj+LjQTIJTaD5zg8TJOkm45KHBTqgKQgVJ2Rh1OxTTeu00Y9IsAyNyAA)

Comment: The only thing that surprises me here is that `mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, a)` passes. The rest of the behavior I would expect, since you've voluntarily widened the types of `a` and `b` to be more ambiguous than they should.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts agreed.  And you don't think there's a better type to give the desired functionality?  I don't know hence asking here.  Thank you.

Comment: There is no possible way you can type `mergeUnique()` so that `mergeUnique(a, b)` succeeds while `mergeUnique(a, a)` fails; the types of `a` and `b` are identical non-union types; the compiler can't tell them apart.  If you want the compiler to remember the individual keys on `a` and `b`, you should not annotate them but let the compiler infer them (`const a: Obj = {...}` is bad, `const a = {...}` is good).

Comment: Thank you @jcalz . That makes sense. If you want to post as an answer I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there are some techniques to manipulate types with index signatures (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51955852/2887218) for an example), the specific check you want to happen here is not possible.  If a value is annotated to be of type `string`, then the compiler will not narrow it down to a[string literal type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), even if you initialize it with a string literal:

```
const str: string = "hello"; // irretrievably widened to string
let onlyHello: "hello" = "hello";
onlyHello = str; //error! string is not assignable to "hello"
```

In the above, the `string` variable `str` is initialized to `"hello"`, but you cannot assign that to a variable of type `"hello"`; the compiler has permanently forgotten that the value of `str` is the string literal `"hello"`.

This "forgetful" widening is true for any annotation of a non-union type.  If the type is a union, the compiler will actually narrow the type of the variable on assignment, at least until the variable is reassigned:

```
const strOrNum: string | number = "hello"; // narrowed from string | number to string
let onlyString: string = "hello";
onlyString = strOrNum; // okay, strOrNum is known to be string
```

Unfortunately, your `Obj` type is a non-union type.  And since it has a `string` index signature, the compiler will only know that a variable annotated as `Obj` will have `string` keys and will not remember the literal value of those keys, even if it is initialized with an object literal with string literal keys:

```
const obj: Obj = { a: 1, b: 2 }; // irretrievably widened to Obj
let onlyAB: { a: 1, b: 1 } = { a: 1, b: 1 };
onlyAB = obj; // error! Obj is missing a and b
```

Thus your `a` and `b` variables, which have been annotated as type `Obj`, are known to the compiler only to be of type `Obj`.  It has forgotten any individual properties inside them.  From the type system's point of view, `a` and `b` are identical.

And thus no matter what crazy type games I try to play with the signature for `mergeUnique()`, nothing I can do will make it so that `mergeUnique(a, b)` succeeds while `mergeUnique(a, a)` fails; the types of `a` and `b` are identical non-union types; the compiler can't tell them apart.

---

If you want the compiler to remember the individual keys on `a` and `b`, you should not annotate them but let the compiler infer them.  If you want to ensure that `a` and `b` are assignable to `Obj` without actually widening them to `Obj`, you can make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) helper function to do that:

```
const asObj = <T extends Obj>(t: T) => t;
```

The function `asObj()` just returns the same value it receives as an argument, and does not change its inferred type.  But since `T` is [constrained](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `Obj`, it will only succeed if the object could be assigned to `Obj`:

```
const a = asObj({ a: undefined }); // {a: undefined}
const b = asObj({ b: 3 }); // {b: number}
const c = asObj({ c: "oopsie" }); // error!
```

Now you have `a` and `b` of narrow types with known string literal property keys, (and a `c` with a compiler error because `"oopsie"` is not a `number | undefined).  And thus the rest of your code behaves as desired:

```
// these all succeed
const res01 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, { b: 3 })
const res02 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, b)
const res03 = mergeUnique(a, { b: 3 })
const res04 = mergeUnique(a, b)
const res05 = mergeUnique({ b: 3 }, { a: undefined })
const res06 = mergeUnique(b, { a: undefined })
const res07 = mergeUnique({ b: 3 }, a)
const res08 = mergeUnique(b, a)
// these all fail
const res09 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, { a: undefined })
const res10 = mergeUnique({ a: undefined }, a)      
const res11 = mergeUnique(a, { a: undefined })
const res12 = mergeUnique(a, a)
```

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBNBOAuOV4EswHMYF4YCIALAUwBtSR8BuGAelpjXnmNTWIDcBDAI1IE8YAdzQATYmGKiYUECnRYAsAChSrGOAEAJMhWRFdlXARLlKVFZv46zxhDXrFmIeAEJ5GbGggwwIWFwQEGiYYLxqMnIGZvgqKqCQsAgA8vAAcgCuALbICJ4wAD6+2TxOxtEU1HQMYc5CUjAAZvAgWR5YhcVZpfCR7ZgqarBWAMpsWLnj2HgV5pZgAmMK0-KpmVkODCAA1lz8ADSr6dmMPtt+QmB9pf1xylD8AA7EMACqYGgAjhnEyTwAVsRgFAADwAFUOrwAfMYAN4wADaAGlGFdtsR+CBGm8ALrIFHEAAeUAkojOGKxMDBMAA-L5OGVkK9kTiYABfO5Ex4uWCNDJgYFocAwLJOTDEd5fH7gyGHABqUIAFCoYDAuMgISqYDwaUyPt9fgCgaCIW8ofstcBdW99T8-oDgeCYAAyN7y80qACUMFhWpYUAy8CuvuUqtVADpI1wLaGw5HwzwY2GYPHgEn2So2TA7g9njB7XDERhxITJss8V0ep1+eJGhgGmyLMp4uBoBoAcgC3h4eqYABGQ48ZAAJnZTaGGgW-AAggAhZA95AD7VL9mF3vLof9sfzARz4wgAGbGBOFpufMA04i7zBDpcNVgaQ8O4txJqiBdmBOokkx8+e1KlAGrejgMJQE2CRtveeCBPaiqLjANbEHWkjSGynoQa2sA8MYsEAvBK4wAAzOyGGvm2wC4R++HwsA+ggCAjzBMQ+Ckcep4uK4dz0DIJAQC8XDkHAGTAMAxBSORsAsBAAAMfbGKK8DipKBoEb2SEoQ2hzwluJHoZJMDSTJo54Ipym2sQanIBp9ZoYOnoGUZJGmWKEoWYq0Y+oRekOcokFScQskACwKa5Kk-B59mOYFMkAKyhUpblSpZOnIHp2lqtZj7IbZpHRbJABsCXmcliqJl56nZZpaG+f5hkxQA7MVSWqalxHsocXC1Vh9WyQAHM14WWeVXUqDxUB8QJQmNFwaCkPlMkAJyDe5CE2ahHUVVlta5fpfk9dJfYyStpVrVVu2dd6ybZvtb6HfJLmJUNkVbYh50bXtdWHSZIphe5nldddQPA6qL7NuDQA)

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for this amazing answer.  Really appreciate it!